# INNER JOIN query producing results in the thousands

Tags: mysql

I hope I explain this right, but I'm having some issues with an `INNER JOIN` query I am building. Let me give it a shot: I have a friends table in which there are a *user1* and a *user2* field, both of which can be a friend of the user, depending who was the inviter, the user or the friend. Now, all these friends are of course users themselves as well and they post messages on their respective pages. All of these messages get stored in a table surprisingly called *"messages"*. I want a user to be able to see all the messages all of his friends have posted and to establish this, I created the following `INNER JOIN` query:

```
SELECT friends.user1, friends.user2, messages.message 
FROM friends
INNER JOIN messages
WHERE (friends.user1 = 'Panda' OR friends.user2 = 'Panda') AND (friends.user1 != 'Panda' OR friends.user2 != 'Panda') AND messages.message != '' AND friends.accepted = '1'
```

(Panda being a test user ofcourse).
What happens is that it indeed selects all of Panda's friends and it selects all of the messages those friends have posted, however, I get ten thousands of results with this query as ALL of the friends have a message one friend has posted in the results. Let me try and clarify this:

Suppose Panda's friend GalwayMonster has posted: "Lees dit boek!".
In the results of the above query it will show up like this:

GalwayMonster "Lees dit boek!"
PaddyPower "Lees dit boek!"
Brother "Lees dit boek!"
Monkey "Lees dit boek!"
(unfortunately SO does not let me post a screenshot as I don't have enough reputation yet, so I guess this will have to do for now - sorry about that)

and so on - every friend it finds, it adds the message GalwayMonster has posted to it, and it does so with each and every post made by any of the other friends.

Obviously I want the correct message to show up at the friend who posted it and if a friend hasn't posted anything, I don't want that friend to show up at all.

What am I doing wrong with this query? Is there something I need to add to have it show the correct message belonging to a friend only with that friend?

I hope I have made this clear enough, but if you have any additional questions, just let me know. Thanks a million!

Comment: maybe friends.user1 != friends.user2 somewhere

Comment: Try adding an `on` clause with a `join` condition between the two tables.

Comment: @nicolas That unfortunately got me the same result - but thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I fixed it. Not really sure actually what the problem is, it gives the desired result (I verified that the result was correct). I changed it into following, just so it may be helpful to somebody else as well:

```
SELECT friends.user1, friends.user2, messages.message, messages.username, messages.remark, messages.posttime
FROM friends
INNER JOIN messages 
WHERE messages.username != 'Panda' AND (messages.username = friends.user1 OR messages.username = friends.user2) AND (friends.user1 = 'Panda' OR friends.user2 = 'Panda') AND messages.message != '' AND messages.remark = ''
```

Still seems a bit long of a query though, but it works and it will have to do for now. A friend of mine suggested to have a look at the UNION or UNION ALL statement to see whether it does something. Anyway, thank you all so much for putting in the effort to help me :) Cheers from Ireland!

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
messages.message IS NOT NULL
```

Instead of

```
messages.message != ""
```

These mean two different things. Maybe this will fix your issue but if you could provide some sample data from the tables and what columns are in the tables that would help. I can update the answer if you provide that if this doesnt fix it.

Comment: I tried this, but it delivers the same results...WHERE (friends.user1 = 'Panda' OR friends.user2 = 'Panda') AND (friends.user1 != 'Panda' OR friends.user2 != 'Panda') AND messages.message IS NOT NULL AND friends.accepted = '1'

Comment: ON (messages.username = friends.user1 OR messages.username = friends.user2)  should work like mfdoran said. I tested this on sqlfiddle but not sure i have schema correct. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6f55e/3

Comment: Sorry, I am at work at the moment, so I can't respond as quickly as I would like to. Will test all of the suggestions and then let you know what the result was. Thanks a million all of you for your efforts!

Answer (score 0):

You need to look at the relationship between the friends and messages tables and adjust your query so that it only pulls back the messages for the friends that you want to see. You will probably want to use an `on` condition added to your `join` for this.

At the moment it looks as though the only limitation you are applying to messages is that the message is not blank.

Without seeing the columns in your tables however it is not possible to provide any further pointers.

Comment: The relationship between friends and messages would be that messages contains a field "username" which is either equal to user1 or user2 in the friends table. Not really sure how to code that as tbh, I haven't done many INNER JOIN queries before. But I have something like this now: INNER JOIN messages ON (messages.username = friends.user1 OR messages.username = friends.user2) but this produces the same result :(

Comment: Have you tried removing the join and just run the initial statement to see if you are getting the correct number of users returned? That would help to check that the where clause on the friends table is working correctly. Once you are sure that you are getting the correct friends back it will make it easier to spot where the issue is with the join to messages

Comment: Tested after removing the join and it returns 30 friends, which is the correct number of friends. So if I understand correctly, the error must lie in the join statement.

Comment: Yeah, it does look as if the join is the culprit though what you have suggested should work. Perhaps try the join again but also select the user name from the messages table so you can see what value that is returning.